# Why does Hibernate query have compile error in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I have this Hibernate code:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from MyTable where status = :status");
```

It compiles and works fine..

But in IntelliJ I get this error reported:

> Can't resolve expression, Can't
>   resolve symbol 'MyTable'

Why is IntelliJ complaining??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IntelliJ is trying to validate your HQL query inside the string itself. To do this, it needs to be configured to know about your hibernate configuration to ensure that a mapping exists for MyTable (it does at runtime, as you know - as it executes!).

Check out the hibernate config section in IntelliJ for your project.

There is probably a way of turning it off if it is more hindrance than help.

Comment: Thanks.  It was actually a setting under Java EE issues \ Persistence QL Problems.  Turned it off and I was good.

Comment: @Marcus thx 4 this clue! In IDEA13 this setting has been moved/renamed I think, but typing `query` in the search box in the Settings -> Inspections dialog reveals it under JPA issues...

Answer (score 30):

Add a "Hibernate" Facet under "Project Structure", then for that Facet select the "hibernate.cfg.xml" file for "Hibernate Configuration". This will let IDEA know about your class to table mapping and will help it recognize those classes in HQL queries.

If you don't use "hibernate.cfg.xml", for example for Spring you may just use "applicationContext.xml" to initialize your datasource, having Hibernate Facet declared may be enough.

Comment: Note that this answer is preferred over turning the inspection off if you use xml mapping. Its an easy setting to make and it helps a lot.

Comment: Thank you tumanov. There was one other prerequisited for your answer to work: the plugin "Hibernate" needs to be activated for your project.

Comment: @tumnanov if in can you know how to do it if i am using spring boot with embedded DB h2, that automatically configures a persistence for me, in this case i don't have a persistence file or hibernate.cf.xml in my directory

Comment: Thanks! This has resolved the issue. As mentioned already, you can use either `hibernate.cfb.xml` or in case of Spring ORM `application-context.xml`

Answer (score 19):

Make sure that you have your Facets configured correctly. I was getting errors in my Spring Data JPA @Query annotations of "Can't resolve symbol" (just within IntelliJ IDEA; the code itself worked fine when I ran it) and I needed to go into Project Structure, Facets and add the JPA facet. (I assume if one is using Hibernate without JPA, then one would just add the Hibernate facet rather than the JPA facet.)

Comment: THISSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS!

For me, it seems that it works by:
1. Adding normal JPA facet, with my persistence.xml file
2. Adding a hibernate facet with nothing in it
(all these in project settings -> facets)

Answer (score 7):

In IntelliJ IDEA 13 for Mac OS X I could find this option as
"Query Language Checks" under "JPA Issues"