# Intellij "Query can't resolve symbol." error with facet set

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

I'm trying to implement query in my code as following:

```
@NamedQuery( name = "Comment.getComments",
                    query = "SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.game=:game")
```

Class *Comment* has following code in it:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery( name = "Comment.getComments",
        query = "SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.game=:game")
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer ident;
    private String player;
    private String game;
    private String comment;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date commentedOn;

    public Comment() {

    }

    public Comment(String player, String game, String comment, Date commentedOn) {
        this.player = player;
        this.game = game;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.commentedOn = commentedOn;
    }
```

In query *Comment c* is underlined red and I'm getting error
 'Can't resolve symbol'.

I know that it has something to do with framework settings.

List of things I've tried:

- File -> Invalidate caches/ Restart
- Set up Facet for my module with Hibernate as Default JPA provider. (I've also attached screenshot of setting)
- Reimport Maven (since I'm using it in project)

Does anyone know, what is causing the problem?

[Facet setting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA7iM.jpg)

Comment: Do you have @Entity on Comment ?

Comment: yes I do, gonna edit the code in here

Comment: there's this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188186/why-does-hibernate-query-have-compile-error-in-intellij

Comment: accorging to this article I've set up JPA facet, but that was not a solution

Comment: What language do you have [injected into query string](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/using-language-injections.html#inject_language_command_example)? It may depend on the JPA (or Hibernate) Facet configured for module: like facet type and JPA provider (in case of JPA facet).
Please also try with the last IDE version from jetbrains.com/idea/download For me it works with the attached sample. and Hibernate QL language injected. 
If issue remains, please share a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: Did you try to add a descriptor in the JPA facet manually?