# IntelliJ IDEA "cannot access org.hibernate.query.QueryProducer" error, but project compiles and runs fine

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I have to apologise in advance that I have tried and utterly failed to produce a small, self-contained program that reproduces this issue, and due to the commercial nature of the project I'm working on neither can I reproduce any of the code responsible here, but I can describe it.

The code has a DAOImpl class which has a 'list' method that takes a DataSourceRequest (custom implementation of the KendoUI "dataSource", sent by the frontend) and returns a DataSourceResponse.  The method calls `request.toDataSourceResponse(org.hibernate.Session, Class<?> clazz)` where the `Class` argument is a JPA entity class.

This method call is where the IDE chokes, producing the error message from the title - `cannot access org.hibernate.query.QueryProducer`.  I have taken the following steps to try to troubleshoot the problem myself, to no avail:

- Invalidated caches and restarted
- Searched Google and StackOverflow for anyone else with a similar problem
- Performed a `mvn clean install` on the whole project to rule out maven glitches

I'm at a loss as to how to proceed from this point.  It isn't blocking me from working (as I say, it compiles and runs fine) but it is irritating to see that little red wavy line under the perfectly valid line of code that isn't even throwing at runtime.

Comment: Seems like an intelliJ bug, are you using any addons/plugins that help analyze code in IntelliJ?

Comment: I think you can get solution from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188186/why-does-hibernate-query-have-compile-error-in-intellij/22766049

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Hibernate query have compile error in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188186/why-does-hibernate-query-have-compile-error-in-intellij)

Comment: Adding the 'hibernate' facet didn't help, and no.  It's a completely stock IntelliJ Ultimate Edition with no third or first party plugins installed beyond what you get out of the box with UE.

Comment: Can you build it from IDE (Build | Build project action)? Please try 2018.2 from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion as it could be related to this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187378. If problem remains, to fix this unfortunately a sample project would be needed.

Comment: Building from IDE didn't clear the error, can check 2018.2 to see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same kind of error. Reason for error was IntelliJ maven repo location was different from maven build repo location. 
Please follow below steps to resolve the issue

1. Build code using command " mvn clean install -Dmaven.repo.local="path/to/local/folder" "
2. Open IntelliJ press " ctrl + shift + s"
3. In search type maven (in the left top corner)
4. Update local repository (in right most corner) to the path you have defined for local repo in step one.